# How to convert Flask request FileStorage file to numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, flask, audio, request, blob

I am trying to convert FileStorage object to numpy ndarray for ASR transcription. This is my code:

```
@app.route('/api/transcribe', methods=\['POST'\])
def transcribe():
   if 'audioFile' not in request.files:
       return 'No audio file provided', 400
   file = request.files\['audioFile'\]
```

Next I must convert it to ndarray with 16000 sample rate and mono channel. How to do that without saving temporary file?

I tried to use soundfile, wav or other libraries, but nothing was useful.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a FileStorage object to a NumPy ndarray you can use the "io.BytesIO" module in Python.

```
def transcribe():
if 'audioFile' not in request.files:
    return 'No audio file provided', 400

file = request.files['audioFile']

# Read the file content as bytes
audio_data = file.read()

# Convert the bytes to a NumPy array using soundfile
with io.BytesIO(audio_data) as f:
    data, samplerate = sf.read(f)

# Check if the audio has multiple channels
if len(data.shape) > 1:
    # Convert to mono by averaging channels
    data = np.mean(data, axis=1)

# Resample the audio to 16kHz if necessary
if samplerate != 16000:
    # You may need to install the resampy package for this
    import resampy
    data = resampy.resample(data, samplerate, 16000)

# Ensure the data is in the correct dtype
data = data.astype(np.float32)

# Now you have your audio data in a NumPy array
print(data.shape)  # Shape of the array
print(samplerate)   # Sample rate of the audio

# Perform ASR transcription or other processing

return 'Transcription done', 200
```

Please make sure to install the required packages (soundfile and resampy) You can install them using pip:

```
pip install soundfile resampy
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I got this error "File "/home/varuzhan/Desktop/armspeech-main/backend/app.py", line 72, in transcribe
    data, samplerate = sf.read(f). soundfile.LibsndfileError: Error opening <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fd6908498f0>: Format not recognised."

Comment: i've tried this, it seems that soundfile does not support format webm, i use ffmpeg to convert to wav, then it runs okay